# How to avoid duplicate fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a button in my fragment (fragment_x) with the below `OnClickListener`:

```
    private void onClickAddButton(View view){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_y fragment_y = new Fragment_y();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rl_activity_main_container, fragment_x);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The problem is that this button is always visible, so clicking it again will add one more fragment_y and the screen gets messed up. How how do I check whether fragment_y has already been added, so that I can avoid creating a duplicate fragment_y?

Comment: Set the button visibility to VIEW.INVISIBLE or disable it, right in the onClickAddButton method.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein that is an option, but i wonder if there is a way to do the check.

Comment: Of course, yes. You might set a boolean variable and check it. OR find the fragment by TAG (give it a tag on creation). But I think I proposed the best (simple + efficient) way to do that: The button is `clickable - clicked - no more clickable`. No hassle with variables, tags, check for conditions...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein TAG sounds like a better option to me. Disabling/disappearing buttons seems old school.

Comment: It depends. Disabling disappearing only requires 1 instruction. Old school isn't a bad thing. Many things in programming remain unchanged since decades. Including the search for the CLEANEST and FASTEST way of doing things. If you use the tag method, then your app will have to **search among all the fragments in the backstack until it finds the one which tag matches the string you pass**... The new school seems **much worse** than the old one!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ask the `FragmentManager` if the Fragment is already added:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) {
        // fragment must be added
        fragment = new Fragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
    } else {
        // fragment already added
    });
```

Comment: how we can display existing fragment from fragment stack instead creating a new one into stack.